# CKfinder image size reduce GIF not working

Tags: php, ckeditor, ckfinder

We are uploading images (GIF animated images 2 MB) via CKfinder. Its actual size is 1.9 MB. After uploading to the server, it converts to 400 KB. Here is the confing of CKfinder.

```
'name'              => 'Images',
'directory'         => 'images',
'maxSize'           => "8M",
'allowedExtensions' => 'bmp,gif,jpeg,jpg,png',
'deniedExtensions'  => '',
'backend'           => 'default',
'maxWidth'    =>       2000,
'maxHeight' =>         1600,
'quality'           => 100
```

We are uploding images to S3. After uploading to S3 its loosing animation of GIF.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2MB GIFs please make sure their width and height doesn't exceed     `'maxWidth'  => 2000,` and `'maxHeight' => 1600,` because image will get resized despite `'maxSize'` being bigger. Please set `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` to bigger vallues than image possible maximum e.g.

```
$config['images'] = array(
    'maxWidth'  => 10000,
    'maxHeight' => 10000,
    'quality'   => 80,
    'sizes' => array(
        'small'  => array('width' => 480, 'height' => 320, 'quality' => 80),
        'medium' => array('width' => 600, 'height' => 480, 'quality' => 80),
        'large'  => array('width' => 800, 'height' => 600, 'quality' => 80)
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks 10000 is working properly. I want to know, why 2500 X 2500 is not working to a 1990 X 1900 image.